# Subtract a value from a hash table on powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Is there a way to subtract one value from another that is inside a hash table?
eg: I have $hash = {"eggs" = 5} and i want to subtract 3 eggs

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`-=` compound assignment operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.3#the-assignment-by-subtraction-operator) to substract a value from an assignment target:

```
$hash['eggs'] -= 3
```